# Opening Default document on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I've a deployed ASP.NET Web API with a website on the same folder that consume it.

When I type the URL on the Browser such as http://domain.com/ it returns a 404, but if I type http://domain.com/index.html it works!

I wanna know if there's a way to configure it on Web API route, define a default route for it, redirecting to my http://domain.com/index.html when I type http://domain.com/

I've tried ti put this on Web.Config without success:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <add value="/index.html" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

**Also, I set up my IIS to only accept index.html default document.** no success =/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this, I just edited my RouteConfig.cs such this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "index.html"
        );
    }
}
```

Now I can get http://domain.com works perfectly!

I'd love If anyone have a best way to achieve this!

Answer (score 2):

Well, It is situational, for what you are doing that is fine.

I have done things like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

I typically still end up with problems when the default mvc portion of web api is hit and so for me I end up doing this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/contact.html");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return File(filePath, "text/html");
        }

        return View();
}
```